# Should zakath payable for investing money in an islamic bank?

Tags: zakat, banking, investment

I have invested a specific amount in an Islamic bank. They will share with me a percentage of profit or loss every month. The profit will change every month. I can't access the capital amount. Should I pay zakat on it? If so, should I pay on the capital amount, the profit, or both?